# How to track tags that we can earn from documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, badges

Actually I want to know that what are the  badges that I can get from documentation. I have earned 3 bronze badges and a silver `Documentation Pioneer` badge. So I want to know the next badges that I can earn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

The Badges button which takes you there is found next to the Ask Question button at the top of most pages.

Comment: [Who needs scrolling when you can dive into the page source and find out what should be appended to the URL after a hashtag?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges#documentation-badges)